# What is wrong with this OleDbReader?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datareader, oledbdatareader

Working in VB, I'm connecting to an access db, and need to get a value from a table.

```
    user = Environment.UserName
    command.CommandText = "SELECT 'nid', 'UserName' FROM qryUSERJOBS WHERE UserName = " & user
    command.Connection = connect
    Using reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            record = reader("nid").ToString
        End While
    End Using
```

When my code steps into  the `Using` statement, reader is created, and my win form is immediately displayed without reading the database or hitting the `End Sub` of the routine that contains it. Any ideas?

Comment: wrap your code in a Try...catch block, and set a breakpoint in there. I think you are missing single quotes around your user variable.

Comment: You havent opened your connection, have you? Always use parameterized  queries instead of string concatenation to prevent sql injection and other issues.

Comment: Don't run the code (or invoke the method) in `OnLoad`, move it to (or invoke the method in) `OnShown`.

Comment: The connection was opened at an earlier part in the code. I put it in a try...catch, and actually received an error for a change. Jeremy, you were correct I was missing the single quotes around my user variable. Thank you all for your responses

Comment: mismatched ticks can be avoided using [Parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29187199/1070452)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- use parameterized query
- avoid sql injection
- Avoid quote mistakes like this one
- Make use of disposable objects

```
Using connect As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    connect.Open()
    Using command As New SqlCommand(
    "SELECT nid, UserName FROM qryUSERJOBS WHERE UserName = @user", 
    connect)
        user = Environment.UserName
        command.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@user", user))

        Using reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                record = reader("nid").ToString
            End While
        End Using

    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score -1):

After putting the code in a Try...Catch block I got an error regarding my parameters. I needed single quotes around my `user` variable.

Code fixed:

```
    user = Environment.UserName
    command.CommandText = "SELECT nid, UserName FROM qryUSERJOBS WHERE UserName = '" & user & "'"
    command.Connection = connect
    connect.Open()
    Try
        Using reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                record = reader("nid").ToString
            End While
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Thanks everyone for your help and advice!

Comment: I hope this is not production code because you should be using Parameters https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: It's my first time using SQL and had no idea what parameters were up till yesterday, the code currently being used resembles the accepted answer for the post.