# Access database won't show in VB.NET DGV with Button. Connection won't open

Tags: vb.net, oledb

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
 Public Class Form1

    Dim dbConnection As OleDbCommand
    Dim dbCommand As OleDbCommand
    Dim dbDataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12. , Data    Source = PatientBilling.mdb.accdb "
    Dim dtPatientBillingTable As DataTable
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub dispAll_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dispAll.Click
        dbConnection = New OleDbConnection() 
        dbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        dtPatientBillingTable = New DataTable()
        dbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM PatientBillingTable")
        dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect
        dbDataAdapter.SelectCommand = dbCommand
        dbDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = dbConnection
        dbConnection.Open() 
        dbDataAdapter.Fill(dtPatientBillingTable)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dtPatientBillingTable
        dbConnection.Close() 

    End Sub
End Class
```

-connection doesn't open
-button doesn't work

Comment: Where are you passing the connection string to the dbConnection?

Comment: It may not like that badly formatted connection string when you get around to passing it to OleDbConnection.  There are [other issues](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29187199/1070452)

Comment: So did you find the answer?

Comment: Yes thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
dbConnection = New OleDbConnection()
```

to this:

```
dbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConnectString)
```