# database connection with a chart

Tags: database, vb.net

I have been trying to figure this out for a few days but every time I try and fix it I encounter the same error. I am trying to implement the data from my database into a candlestick style chart.Every time I run it i'm faced with this same error:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)."

I have used a combination of the limited resources given to me and code that I found here on a previously answered question to create the following code.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1


Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
Dim provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
Dim dataFile As String = "C:\Users\Ian\Documents\A2 Woking\Computing\Database1\Database_data_source .accdb"
Dim DatabasePass As String = "DatabasePW"
Dim connString As String = provider & dataFile
Dim execute As OleDbDataReader

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString

    Dim objDataAdapter As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select Time, Open, High, Low, Last FROM EUR_USD_TB", myConnection)

    myConnection.Open()

    execute = objDataAdapter.ExecuteReader

    While execute.Read
        chartTemplate.Series("dataSeries").Points.AddXY(execute("Time"), execute("Low"), execute("High"), execute("Open"), execute("Last"))
    End While
    ' Close the reader and the connection
    execute.Close()
    myConnection.Close()


End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be appreciated i'm sure its something annoyingly simple I don't get.

The path is correct---
The database is not protected by a password, that variable is for later---
The query works in access---
This same code works perfectly for accessing a separate table in my login

Comment: Are any of the database fields null?

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception ?

Comment: execute = objDataAdapter.ExecuteReader throws the exception, no null fields

Comment: there is usually more details like in the inner exception; `Time` is a reserved word, you need to escape it.  The same code cant work perfectly elsewhere unless it is the same table...the SQL is integral to the code

Comment: No actually I don't know,  execute = objDataAdapter.ExecuteReader is the next line of code to be run so does that mean it stops working at myConnection.Open()

Comment: No I mean't the code for the connection, I should have elaborated. Obviously the table name and query where different

Comment: Almost mentioned in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29187199/1070452) applies to your code.  I already told you what is probably wrong with the SQL even though you havent given us the full error message

Comment: yea thanks it works now, it was the column headers like you said

Comment: is there a way to up vote you or something, i'm new to this site