# Unrecognized database format when filling DataAdapter

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to use listboxes to categorize data and I am trying to use SQL to do so.

[form picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpyzF.png)

that link is what the form looks like know and what i'm trying to do - to use the listboxes to view the records by student year.

For the first list box here is the code for the first listbox to sort the data by year:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class viewStudent

Private Sub viewStudent_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ProjDataSet1.Details' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.DetailsTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.ProjDataSet1.Details)
    ' OleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet11)
End Sub

Private Sub lstYear_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstYear.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim Year, SQLString As String
    Dim dtDetails As New DataTable()
    Dim dbDataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source = proj.accdb"
    Year = lstYear.Text
    SQLString = "SELECT * FROM Details WHERE Year = " & "'" _
        & Year & "'" & ""
    dbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLString, ConnectString)
    dbDataAdapter.Fill(dtDetails)
    grdRecords.DataSource = dtDetails
End Sub
End Class
```

But i get the error in the link below:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZQ0c.png)

Can someone help to fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: I would use a combo instead of listbox, then use a DataView to apply a filter (rather than requerying the db)

Comment: thanks will try that now

Comment: What version of Access?  I think ACE/12.0 would be more appropriate

Comment: `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0...`  see [ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/) Also, those DB Provider objects should be disposed of when done.  For  2013: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2013/

Comment: i have access 2013 and it says the provider is oledb4.0

Comment: what is "it" that says Jet.OleDB 4.0?? that is for older Access versions.  see the link

Comment: in what section would i dispose at them, at the very end? and is there any example you could give like which objects? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29187199/1070452.  anythng which has a Dispose method should be disposed of when you are done with it

Comment: i am still having difficulties adapting the code. can anyone possibly adapt mine or at least tell me what i have to do?

Comment: Is your copy of Access 2013 the 32-bit version or the 64-bit version?

Comment: it is the 64-bit version

Comment: @Sohs If this answered your question, you should click the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" provider is the older 32-bit provider that can only work with .mdb database files. To work with an .accdb database you need to use the newer "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" provider.

Since you have the 64-bit version of Access 2013 installed you already have the 64-bit version of the ACE provider. All you need to do is

1. Modify the properties of your .NET project to run as a 64-bit application (ref: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx)), and
2. Change the connection string in your code to use `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.