# Query will not update SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

In the below code, my second query will not insert into the SQL database, but the first one will update.  I can copy the query (from the msgbox i added for testing) and paste it in SQL Server Management Studio, and it will execute fine. I also do not get any error messages back from SQL, though i'm not sure if that code is correct (it was copied + pasted from another source). Also, can i simplify the code to pass both queries at the same time?

```vb
Dim Conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection         'sql server datastream connection
Dim Cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand             'sql command vars
Dim SqlQuery As String                                      'string var used to hold various SQL queries
Dim data As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader             'datareader object variable
Dim MVDataset As New DataSet
Dim MVDatatable As DataTable
Dim MVDatarow As DataRow

Private Sub MVUpdateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MVUpdateButton.Click

  vbyn = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to update Tally Sheet Master Variables?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Changes to these variables will change the functionality of the Tally Sheet!", vbYesNo, )
  Try
    Select Case vbyn
      Case vbNo
        GoTo MVTableUpdateBypass
      Case vbYes
        'get new data from textboxes
        Vers = TextBox1.Text
        If TextBox2.Text = True Then
          Testing = 1
        Else
          Testing = 0
        End If
        FlatFeeCharge = TextBox3.Text
        PrepricingCharge = TextBox4.Text
        SendMailAcct = TextBox5.Text
        SendMailPW = TextBox6.Text
        TestingEmail = TextBox7.Text
        PrePricingEmail = TextBox8.Text
        ImperataEmail = TextBox9.Text

        'update existing active row to mark inactive
        SqlQuery = "Update MasterVars set Active = 0 where PKEY = " & PKEY & ";"
        MsgBox(SqlQuery)
        If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
          Conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SQL01;Initial Catalog=TallySheet;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
        End If
        Conn.Open()
        Dim MVDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, Conn)
        Dim MVUpdateCommand As SqlCommand
        MVUpdateCommand = New SqlCommand(SqlQuery)
        MVDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = MVUpdateCommand

        'insert new active row
        SqlQuery = "Insert into MasterVars (Vers, Testing, FlatFeeCharge, PrePricingCharge, SendMailAcct, SendMailPW, TestingEmail, PrePricingEmail, ImperataEmail, DTS, UserName, Active) Values (" & "'" & Vers & "', " & Testing & ", '" & FlatFeeCharge & "'" & ", '" & PrepricingCharge & "'" & ", '" & SendMailAcct & "'" & ", '" & SendMailPW & "'" & ", '" & TestingEmail & "'" & ", '" & PrePricingEmail & "'" & ", '" & ImperataEmail & "'" & ", '" & Date.Now & "'," & "'QGDOMAIN\" & Environment.UserName & "'," & 1 & ");"
        MsgBox(SqlQuery)
        Dim MVInsertCommand As SqlCommand
        MVInsertCommand = New SqlCommand(SqlQuery)
        MVDataAdapter.InsertCommand = MVInsertCommand
        MVDataAdapter.Fill(MVDataset, "MasterVars")
      End Select
    Catch ex As SqlException
      Dim i As Integer
      Dim errormessages As String
      errormessages = ""
      For i = 0 To ex.Errors.Count - 1
        errormessages = errormessages & " " & ("Index #" & i.ToString() & ControlChars.NewLine _
                & "Message: " & ex.Errors(i).Message & ControlChars.NewLine _
                & "LineNumber: " & ex.Errors(i).LineNumber & ControlChars.NewLine _
                & "Source: " & ex.Errors(i).Source & ControlChars.NewLine _
                & "Procedure: " & ex.Errors(i).Procedure & ControlChars.NewLine)
      Next i
    Console.WriteLine(errorMessages.ToString())
  End Try

  'reload form with updated variables
  Conn.Close()
  Conn.Dispose()
MVTableUpdateBypass:
End Sub
```

Comment: Dont use GoTo, Do use SQL parameters, dont use global DB provider objects.  I am not sure an Update command can be used to fill a DataTable

Comment: Can you please provide some more information?  I am highly skilled in SQL server and VBA.... but now I got the instruction that I'm supposed to use VB.NET....   The update query works, but the insert does not.   If i shouldn't be using GoTo and global DB objects, then what should I be using?

Comment: There are many many many posts here ( [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29187199/1070452)) which show how to use parameters, dispose of objects and so forth.

Comment: In this simple case you should just use "return" instead of GOTO. And you really need to use parameterized queries, or even better stored procedures, instead of building up a string like this and executing it.

Comment: Are the prices and fees really stored as strings?

Comment: I am revising the code to use parameterized queries, and yes the fees are stored as strings... but that was a mistake....

However, my actual questions aren't answered... 
Why is query #2 not updating the SQL table(s)?
Can i pass both queries at the same time?

Comment: And who executes these queries? Adapter.Fill runs the SelectCommand as I have said above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fill method of the SqlDataAdapter executes the `SelectCommand` not the `UpdateCommand` or the `InsertCommand`. In any case these two commands (and the `DeleteCommand`) are executed when you call the `Update` method of the adapter.
Moreover the Update method runs the commands looking for rows changed/added/deleted in the DataTable/DataSet retrieved by the SelectCommand and works only for those rows.

But you don't need an SqlDataAdapter to execute your two queries. You should simply construct an SqlCommand with both texts separated by a semicolon and call ExecuteNonQuery

```
SqlQuery = "Update MasterVars set Active = 0 where PKEY = @key;" & _
           "Insert into MasterVars (Vers, Testing, .....) VALUES (@p1, @o2, ....)"
Using Conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SQL01;......")
Using cmd = New SqlCommand(SqlQuery, Conn)
    Conn.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@key", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PKEY 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = vers 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = testing
    ... and so on with other parameters .... 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
```

In this incomplete example (too many parameters to write down) I have concatenated the two sql texts in a single string and prepared it with parameter placeholders. Then I build the parameter collection with the exact datatypes required by your table and finally call `ExecuteNonQuery` to run everything on the database side.

Notice that is not needed to keep global objects like the connection or the command. It is always better to create a local variable, use and destroy it when done. In particular disposable objects like the connection and the command should always created in a Using block

Comment: Thank you.... the entire data adapter thing is confusing to me. I'm getting a lot of new information at the same time.  I appreciate the clear, concise answer.