# What is a simple example of using prepared statements in vb net using Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0

Tags: vb.net

Hallo good people of Stack overflow.
For some reason i want to keep working with ms Access as the database using vb net.

My code works well but only if i work directly with user inputs. Which makes my system prone to sql injections.

I have seen some examples on google that show use binding of parameters in prepared statements using vbn.et.

Unfortunately those examples do not support "Provider" key word in my connection string for ms Access table.

Can someone who understands this help me modify my vb code below to work with binding of parameters using Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 as connection string?

I want to avoid saying "where password =  " & supplier_password
but say something like "where password = @supplier_password "
and later provide the supplied password text.

Here is my vb net code.

```
    Private Sub test_password()


    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    myConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source =C:\books\author.mdb"

    Dim counter As Int16

    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT * FROM users where password =  '" & pass.Text & "'"


    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)

    counter = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    myConnection.Close()

    If counter > 0 Then
        MsgBox("password was found")
    Else
        MsgBox("password was NOT found")

    End If

End Sub
```

I have used the appropriate

```
          Imports System.Data.OleDb
          Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Many thanks

Comment: `OleDb` is for Access, `SqlClient` is for SqlServer.  You usually do not need both.  That is a fairly crude log on mechanism if they just need to guess a password rather than the password used by a particular userId.  Also passwords should never be stored as plaintext, but hashed.

Comment: hi plutonix. its just a simple example not to get complicated. Plus i have now learned what SqlClient is doing. Thanks for your response

Comment: Aside from Steve's great answer, also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29187199/1070452

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a version of your code with parameters and correct use of disposable objects

```
Private Sub test_password()
    ' Do not return all the fields, just count....'
    ' ...and password is a reserved keyword in access...'
    ' need square brackets around it otherwise ...syntax error...'
    Dim str = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users where [password] =  @pass"
    Using myConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;....")
    Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)

        myConnection.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = pass.Text
        ' ExecuteScalar returns the first column of the first row from your query'
        Dim counter = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        If counter > 0 Then
             MsgBox("password was found")
        Else
             MsgBox("password was NOT found")
        End If
    End Using 
    End Using    
End Sub
```

The [Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) ensures that every disposable object (connection and command in this context) are correctly disposed when you have finished to use them.

The parameter placeholder *@pass* is inserted in place of the actual value and a parameter is added to the command parameter collection with the matching datatype expected by the field and the correct value.

Note that in OleDb, parameters placeholders are usually represented by a question mark `?` but Access accepts also parameters placeholders expressed with the `@xxxx` format. However, the parameters should be added in the parameter collection, following the same order in which their placeholders appears in the command text.

Comment: Great. Just what i was looking. Thank you very much.

Comment: I see. Still a lot to learn. I am surprised by the good quality of answers from stack over flow , in short perods of time and often with simple applicable solutions. Beats encyclopedia any day.... except for the harsh no nonsense moderators

Comment: @webzy SO is a very numerous community and it is driven by the search of quality. Without moderators being sometime 'harsh' the downfall into a big forum totally anarchist will be immediate. There are thousands of pages in [help] explaining the rules. Of course imposing them with teaching is a thing, without explanation it is another. See you again on SO