# inserting into database in vb doesnt work

Tags: vb.net

I have this code that gives syntax error in INSERT INTO statement..any help ?

```
Dim lo As String = "INSERT INTO tblTrans(Book ID,Student ID,Date Borrowed,Returned )VALUES( @parm1, @parm2 , @parm3 , @parm4 )"
Dim cmd55 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(lo, connectors2)
cmd55.Parameters.Add("@parm1", OleDb.OleDbType.WChar, 10).Value = str5
cmd55.Parameters.Add("@parm2", OleDb.OleDbType.WChar, 5).Value = std
cmd55.Parameters.Add("@parm3", OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = str11
cmd55.Parameters.Add("@parm4", OleDb.OleDbType.WChar, 255).Value = str12
cmd55.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd55.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: str5,std,str12 are declared as strings and str11 is declared as date

Comment: If you have poorly named columns with spaces in them, you need to escape them.  `([Book ID], [Student ID]...)`  You also need to escape Date because that is a reserved word.  Advice: go back and use better column names

Comment: you mean I should change my column-names to "ex: BookID instead of book ID " ??

Comment: I would.  The alternative is remembering to escape them in every query (same for Date).  See also [this answer about disposing of db objects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29187199/1070452). FYI: One of several MSDN [List of Access Reserved Words](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286335)

Comment: well yes it worked...thank you very much :)))

Comment: Column names are not according to standards. Also you need to put space around `VALUES`.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement should be after changing column names,

```
Dim lo As String = "INSERT INTO tblTrans(Book_ID,Student_ID,Date_Borrowed,Returned ) VALUES ( @parm1, @parm2 , @parm3 , @parm4 )"
```

Also Convert `str11` to date before inseting.