# How to use Parameterized Queries in OracleDataReader with stringbuilder in VB.Net?

Tags: database, vb.net, oracle, parameters, stringbuilder

I have this code for retrive data from my oracle database:

```
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        sb.AppendLine("SELECT * FROM NOULGH")
        Using dar As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader = Ibr.DataReader(sb.ToString)
            While dar.Read()
                page_no = dar("PRINT_NO").ToString()
                page_no1 = dar("PAGE_NO1").ToString()
            End While
        End Using
```

Now i want to retrieve the data from Oracle database using parameter.

```
Private Function createCSVBody(ByVal reader As String)
    Try
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        sb.AppendLine("SELECT * FROM NOULGB WHERE PRINT_NO=@readerno")
        sb.AppendLine(New OracleParameter("@readerno", OracleDbType.Char, reader, ParameterDirection.Input).ToString)
        Using dar As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader = Ibr.DataReader(sb.ToString)
            While dar.Read()
                page_no = dar("PRINT_NO").ToString()
                page_no1 = dar("PAGE_NO1").ToString()
        End Using
End Function
```

But it is not working for me. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you tried it as just a string, instead of a stringbuilder?

Comment: The parameter does not go in the AppendLine of the stringbuilder.

Comment: So how could i use it?

Comment: [example of how to use SQL parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29187199/1070452)