# Moving listview checkbox to the last column?

Tags: vb.net, listview

Below is an update to your question: This is from the module.  I took all this over after someone quit and its been a bit of a mess.

```
Public Function MPCS_SELECT_SQL(ByVal strSQL As String, Optional ByRef readerObj As OleDbDataReader = Nothing) As OleDbDataReader 'ADODB.Recordset
    Try


        If OPEN_CONNECTIONS() = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error connecting to database.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            MPCS_SELECT_SQL = Nothing
            Exit Function
        Else


            If Not readerObj Is Nothing Then
                If readerObj.IsClosed - False Then readerObj.Close()
            End If
            Dim cmdMPCS As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conMPCS)

            MPCS_SELECT_SQL = cmdMPCS.ExecuteReader()
            cmdMPCS.Dispose()

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString & "     " & strSQL)
        Stop
        Return Nothing
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: The ListView is (still) ill-suited for data displays; the checkbox is associated with the ListViewItem, so it is always and forever in column1.  Use a DGV and you can put the columns in any order you want.

Comment: ...all that code to populate the rows and columns and set the alternating backcolor could be reduced to `dgvProducts.DataSource = mySimpleDataTable`.  As a bonus, things like quantity and price (numeric values!) wont be converted to text

Comment: not much to learn for the default behavior: the one line I showed creates all the columns and shows all the rows. Each column knows what the datatype of the data is; edits to the DGV will automagically flow back into the DT

Comment: I'm not using a datatable or OleDbDataAdapter so I'm not sure how to make it work.

Comment: How are you getting the data from the DB now; what do you do with that SQL?  Why are you creating a DGV instead of adding it in the IDE designer?

Comment: I did add it to the desiger.  Everything is done in the vb module with OleDbDataReader's.  I assumed my only problem now was figuring out how to fill a datatable since I didn't use a dataadapter.

Comment: `Dim dgvStock As New DataGridView` creates a new control; you dont need that.  `myDataTable,Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)` will fill the DT, you dont have to have a DataAdapter, but it would probably make sense in the long run.  then `dgvNameOnForm.DataSource = myDataTable`

Comment: I guess in my case then it would just be `DataGridView1.DataSource = rsMPCS` But that doesn't work

Comment: I have no idea what `MPCS_SELECT_SQL` is or what it returns.  does the rs mean it returns an old fashioned RecordSet?

Comment: Update the post above.  You are correct.

Comment: `myDataTable.Load(rsMPCS .ExecuteReader)`  it might work even though you have already executed the reader in that funky sub.

Comment: `ExecuteReader' is not a member of 'OleDbDataReader'`

Comment: Oops.  Sorry - it would be the OleDBCOmmand object which you threw away in that method.  That thing is of no value.  Not only are you not closing and disposing of things as you should (your app will leak). but queries tend to be specialized that they dont lend themselves to helper things like that.

Comment: I got it `myDataTable.Load(rsMPCS)` Now I just gotta figure out how to work with the column arranges and am I able to do checkboxes and things I originally was looking for so someone can add to cart?  Is there a good way with DataGrid to do something like that.

Comment: The column order is based on the SQL, so you can often just change that.  To add "virtual" fields, add them to the SQL: `...Picked As Boolean`.  You can also add columns manually in the IDE and gobs and gobs of properties to control the display, display order, color, format etc

Comment: Can you tell me where I am not disposing things so I can learn from that?  If you have time.  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: everything and anything which has a `Dispose` method means that it allocates some sort of resource under the hood and should be Disposed when you are done with it.  I did not see your `cmdMPCS.Dispose()` - the more common way is `Using` blocks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29187199/1070452