# How to validate a null value in a maskedtextbox phone number input mask

Tags: vb.net

I want to check for null values. using this code below. i am still getting values in the textbox. The values i am getting in the textbox are "(   )   -"...

```
If Text_Phone.Text IsNot "" Then
If BuildSqlFlag = True Then
BuildSql = BuildSql & " AND " & "Phone = " & Text_Phone.Text
Else
BuildSql = "Phone = " & Text_Phone.Text
End If
BuildSqlFlag = True
End If
```

i am not exactly sure what is needed from my code to be changed to  i even tried the following:

```
If Text_Phone.Text IsNot "(   )   -" Then
```

But that was no help.

Comment: please do not downvote as i can fix my question if needed. just please explain what i need to improve.

Comment: Start by removing irrelevant tags some of those are mutually exclusive. Hover the mouse to read the summary for each if you arent sure

Comment: i removed two tags. thank you for the input. is there anything else i should fix?

Comment: DOnt concat strings to build a SQL query.  Use parameters

Comment: is there an example that i can use to build parameters? new to programming but these guidelines are helping me a lot to get used to vs.

Comment: [There are gobs and gobs of examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29187199/1070452) here.

Comment: @Plutonix you rock. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the TextMaskFormat to exclude prompt and literals.

```
Text_Phone.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals
```

[MaskFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskformat(v=vs.110).aspx)

Then when you do `Text_Phone.Text` it will be equal to `""` if it's empty.

Comment: Thank you so much. never knew maskformat can exclude literals. please give an upvote to future visitors as i know many people will use masktextboxes instead of textboxes for phone number validation.

Answer (score 1):

'Validate phone number in this format: 999-999-9999

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
     ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim phoneNumber As New Regex("\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}")
        If phoneNumber.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text) Then
            TextBox2.Text = "Valid phone number"
        Else
            TextBox2.Text = "Not Valid phone number"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

'Validate phone number in this format (999)999-9999

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As System.Object, _
 e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim phoneNumber As New Regex("\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4}")
        If phoneNumber.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text) Then
            TextBox2.Text = "Valid phone number"
        Else
            TextBox2.Text = "Not Valid phone number"
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i will use this on another input where i am using a textbox for a phone number. Thank you this was useful gave it an upvote. Please give this question an upvote. these two answer will help future visitors. thanks