# Select seq from sqlite_sequence where name="table_name" sintax error by double quote

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

On the table userRecords the field **userRecordIDNumber** is defined like

```
userRecordIDNumber INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

so SQLite can create the sqlite_sequence table

I need to read the last **userRecordIDNumber** inserted

My code just after the Try Using

```
Dim LastRecordIDNumber as Integer
cmdConnection.CommandText = "SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence where name="userRecords""
LastRecordIDNumber = CType(cmdConnection.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
```

But VB.net didn't accept the double quote after the table name

**Do I need to use a special String concatenation trick or something similar?**

Comment: Use [SQL Parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29187199/1070452) especially with SQLite. If the name was `O'Henry` your query would crash

Comment: @Plutonix Solved !! Using 'cmdConnection.CommandText = "SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence where name=@userRecords"' Thanks. Do I need to deleted the question or write the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution as suggested by @Plutonix

```
Dim LastRecordIDNumber as Integer
cmdConnection.CommandText = "SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence where name=@userRecords"
cmdConnection.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userRecords", "userRecords")
LastRecordIDNumber = CType(cmdConnection.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
```